# computing a value in a dataframe colum from another column, but only if a condition in a 3rd column is met

Tags: python, pandas

When I do this:

```
import pandas as pd

table={'x':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
   'y':[1,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,2,2,3],
   'z':[0,0,2,2,0,1,2,0,4,5,0,2,0,2,3],
   'type':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c']}

df=pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['x','y','z','type'])

mask = df.z==0

df.x[mask] = 1./df.y[mask]
```

I get the desired behavior, but pandas complains and says:

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df.x[mask] = 1./df.y[mask]

Now, this is just a tiny little df here and so I can make the warning go away making the changes in column 'x' row by row with iloc or suchlike. But in my actual data analysis program the df is on the larger side, so the iloc approach slows things down quite a bit.

Is there a better way to get the changes made in column x, using column y values, only in rows where a condition is true in column z?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` to avoid chain indexing... and assignment on the chain index

```
df.loc[mask, 'x'] =  1. / df.loc[mask, 'y']
```

---

That said.  You could do the chain indexing for the values you are trying to assign.  You only got the warning for trying to assign to an object after chain indexing....

This works as well

```
df.x.values[mask] = 1. / df.y[mask]
```

As well as

```
df.loc[mask, 'x'] = 1. / df.y[mask]
```

Comment: @Charlie_M da nada!